# Why does this error show when I try this in a loop but not otherwise?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple program in python :

This code works. It gives output as 3 asterisks after 4 spaces

```
j=4
i=3
print(' '*j,'*'*i)
```

But the same thing when I try using for loop as below:

```
print ('Enter a positive odd number')
n = input ()
for i in range(1,n+1,2):
  j= int(n/2)
  print(' '*j,'*'*i)
  j=j-1
```

I get below error:

> "C:/Users/NIKHIL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/asterisk
>   pattern.py", line 3, in 
>       for i in range(1,n+1,2): TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Can someone please let me know why concatenation error is coming only in for loop?, earlier code also has i and j defined as integer

Comment: Please show us the definition of `n`.

Comment: `n` is a string, probably derived from user input

Comment: it should be `n = int(input () )`

Comment: Have put code in main question

Comment: oh okay thank you so much Chris_Rands,I'll try that but since I am not concatening n, is there a need for n also to be integer?

Comment: If you're going to to math operations on it, it needs to be a number type. There is a different internal representation for `"1"`, and `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your input `n` which is always saved as a string into an integer :

```
for i in range(1, int(n)+1, 2):
```

You can also cast it directly in the declaration :

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive odd number"))
```